# PHP Array - How to loop through an array

Tags: php

My array is as follows:

```
Array ( [questions] => q1 [qnum] => 1 [qtext] => I love crisps [page] => 1 )
Array ( [questions] => q2 [qnum] => 2 [qtext] => I love chocolate [page] => 1 )
```

All I would like to do is print the contents of the array in a loop, so it looks something like:

```
q1 1 I love crisps
q2 2 I love chocolate
```

If anyone could supply the PHP and HTML code, that would be great, thanks.

This is a multi-dimensional array - I should have stated that.  In addition, I want to be able to access each element of the array row, for example.  I also want to just access the [qtext] element on its own.

Is this possible?

Homer.

Comment: You say 'Array' but then list two Arrays.  Is this a multidimensional array or are you giving two separate examples?

Comment: Soo basic. You need to do your homework first.

Comment: *(reference)* http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php#UlRGTQ==

Comment: @Josh [How to convert int* to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699534/how-to-convert-int-to-int) got three upvotes in the last hour; things don't get much more basic than that :)

Comment: @all - thanks for the feedback - please see the updated question.  Yes, multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @Michael - headed there right now ;)

Comment: Basic questions should be fine as long as they are clear.  The downvotes puzzle me.

Comment: I downvoted because you're asking for the PHP and HTML code, rather than an explanation. To me it simply sounds like you just want someone to fix your code for you so you can carry on whatever else you were doing without wanting to learn how to do it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `foreach` construct here.

```
foreach($arr as $value)
{
    echo "$value ";
}
```

If you wanted to print out the keys too you could use:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key: $value ";
}
```

And if you just want to print out for debugging there's always

```
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) like so

```
$arr = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
echo "$key => $value<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: If I write that code, I would change the echo line in to:
echo $key . ' => ' . $value . "<br/>\n";

Answer (score 0):

If it's just an array of arrays, you would do something like this:

```
foreach ($multi_array as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $item)
    {
        echo $item['questions'], ' ', $item['qnum'], ' ', $item['qtext'], '<br>';
    }
}
```